# Web::Scraper Cannot find <link> or <meta> elements in the <body> of an HTML document

Tags: perl, scraper

I've been staring a this for an hour now and I'm throwing in the towel.

I am attempting to scrape some data from a web page. Here's a snippet with some of the data I'm trying to extract:

```
<span itemprop="thumbnail" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageObject">
  <link itemprop="url" href="http://blahblah.org/video/thumbnail_23432230.jpg">
  <meta itemprop="width" content="1280">
  <meta itemprop="height" content="720">
</span>
```

I want to grab the value of the href property form the  tag with the Web::Scraper module. Here's the relevant perl code:

```
my $div = scraper {
  process 'span[itemprop="thumbnail"] > link', url => '@href';
};
my $res = $div->scrape( $html );
$url = $res->{url};
```

No matter what I try, $url returns undefined. I'm using version .36 of the Web::Scraper module.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is because of a bug in [`HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath`](https://metacpan.org/module/HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath). It has a naive understanding of `<link>` and `<meta>` elements, insisting that they belong only in the `<head>` element, even if they have an `itemprop` attribute.

The way elements are treated is based on the hashes in [`HTML::Tagset`](https://metacpan.org/module/HTML::Tagset), and a fix of sorts can be effected by hacking this data.

If you add this to the top of your program

```
use HTML::Tagset;

for (qw/ link meta /) {
    $HTML::Tagset::isHeadElement{$_}       = 0;
    $HTML::Tagset::isHeadOrBodyElement{$_} = 1;
}
```

then it "fixes" the specific situation in your question, but of course a proper solution should take account of the `itemprop` attributes as well as the tags.

Comment: Bingo! Thanks!

You had a small typo:

    use HTML::Tagset; (lowercase "s" needed)